Do symfony voters only work in a controller?
For a symfony project (API) I have for some situations quite complicated access rights. So I moved the decision making to a custom Voter, which in my opinion is nice because the this decision process is separated from the class fetching my data.
My application currently works like this:
The api gets a call with an id, so my view method in the controller just looks like this:
    public function view(int $id): View
    {
        $charge = $this->chargeService->view($id);

        return $this->createView($charge);
    }

Depending on the user rights and the properties of the found object the user might or might not be able to see the requested item.
So I added these attributes before the method:
    #[
        Route(path: '/{id}', name: 'view', requirements: ['id' => '\d+'], methods: ['GET']),
        ViewContext(['groups' => ['view'], 'view_link' => true]),
        IsGranted(
            'CHARGE_VIEW',
            subject: 'chargeDto',
            message: 'No looking here, bro',
            statusCode: 403
        ),
        OA\Get(
            operationId: 'item_view',
            description: 'Get one item by id',
            summary: 'Get one item by id',
            tags: ['Charge Data'],
            responses: [
                new OA\Response(
                    response: 200,
                    description: 'Success',
                    content: new OA\JsonContent(ref: new Model(type: ChargeDto::class), type: 'object')
                ),
                new OA\Response(response: 401, description: 'Unauthorized'),
                new OA\Response(response: 403, description: 'Forbidden (access denied)'),
                new OA\Response(response: 404, description: 'Error not found'),
            ]
        )
    ]
    public function view(int $id): View
    {
        $charge = $this->chargeService->view($id);

        return $this->createView($charge);
    }

This now gives me the error message :
Could not find the subject "chargeDto" for the #[IsGranted] attribute. Try adding a "$chargeDto" argument to your controller method.
No surprise here, because I pass an integer in and give an DTO object back, neither of which is my entity. The Voter needs information about the user and the entity or alternatively the resulting DTO to decide if it is allowed to see it.
Is my custom voter useless here? Or can I also be called from the "chargeService" class where I fetch the entity?
